# how to statistics the content of bracket (include the bracket )in the string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like `23ert[word]45y[li]dfdf[beautiful]adf`. I want to collect each word surrounded by brackets `[...]` into an array or collection. The example string would have `[word]`, `[li]`, and `[beautiful]` in the array or collection.

How can I use regular expressions, or any other methods, to do this?

edit:when i use the follow methods veru good,but when the string as 56[ty[df]yu]5689,i want to only get [df],how modify the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static public List<String> collect(String str) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[.+?\\]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find())
        list.add(m.group());
    return list;
}
```

Comment: sorry,i have a question  your method very good,but when i using the string as 45[d[12]f],i want to get [12],useing your method i cannot this,can you again help me?thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\[.+?\\]");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Try this one.

Comment: sorry,i have a question  your method very good,but when i using the string as 45[d[12]f],i want to get [12],useing your method i cannot this,can you again help me?thank you

Comment: @pengwang While you could do this with a regular exrpession, do you also want to match for example [[[something]]]?